# Change AWS-cognito mail verification code from 24 to 48 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Am using aws Amplify with Cognito user-pool, It works great but i want to change the default 24 hours expire date of sign-up verification code to 48 hours. I cant find any resource online to help. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "verification codes," do you mean the temporary passwords your users receive when an account is created for them? If so, that is in the General Settings > Policies section.

Comment: Thanks for reply dude, but i mean the 6 digits code to confirm sign-up. This one is 24 hours valid per default, I want to increase this expire date to 48 hours or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is not answered and after a long search we decided to do work a around.

- Lambda trigger to re-send new verification code after its expired using admin get user and checking createdAt and email verified attributes. Better than nothing.